# Set web address managed with Google apps to redirect to an external website

Tags: azure, dns, google-apps, cname, a-records

I have a domain (email, calendar etc.) that is managed with Google Apps.

I want that when user accesses the naked domain name (i.e. mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com), it should redirect to a website stored in Windows Azure.

Now here is what I see when trying to do this via Windows Azure:

> You can point custom domain names to your Windows Azure web sites. Windows Azure must verify that you are authorized to configure the custom domain name to point to your Windows Azure web site. To verify authorization, create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to mydomain.azurewebsites.net, or from awverify.www.mydomain.com to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this step by step blogpost, that explain how to do this:

[How to: configure custom DNS names for multiple sub domain-based Azure web sites](http://stefanjohansson.org/2012/12/how-to-configure-custom-dns-names-for-multiple-subdomain-based-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the control panel for dns settings for the domain. this is normally supplied by the registrar/web hotel that you used to buy the domain. As far as I know, Google still doesn't manage the domains as actual registrar so you would likely have it managed by someone else.

The control panel should have a page for dns management where there already are about 20 entries for Google apps. change the www and naked domain A entries to point to the IP-address specified in Azure and add additional CNAME entries for awverify as requested by Azure.